# sql query with string of a date as parameter doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to write a query with jpa, but I can't.
I tried:

```
@Query(value="select count(id_ass) from assenza where id_dip=?1 and data_ass between ?2 and ?3", nativeQuery = true)
Integer getAssenzeByid_dipmese(int id_dip,String inizio, String fine);
```

but i get `ERROR: operator does not exist: date >= character varying`

then I tried to use

```
 @Query(value="select count(id_ass) from assenza where id_dip=?1 and data_ass >= ?2 and  data_ass<= ?3", nativeQuery = true)
Integer getAssenzeByid_dipmese(int id_dip,String inizio, String fine);
```

but I get the same error

then I tried to convert the strings in date but it didn't work...
can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: which format have inizio and fine . Mysql wants 2021-10-29

Comment: the format is 2021-10-29, do i need to add '-' to the end of the string?

Comment: *but i get ERROR: operator does not exist: date >= character varying* This is not MySQL error message. Check your DBMS.

Comment: i also doubt that mysql is the problem here and no you dpn't need to add single quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the variables are Strings, they're passed as varchars.
You have to explicitly cast the varchars as dates.

```java
@Query(value="select count(id_ass) from assenza where id_dip=?1 and data_ass between CAST(?2 AS DATE) and CAST(?3 AS DATE)", nativeQuery = true)
Integer getAssenzeByid_dipmese(int id_dip,String inizio, String fine);
```

Comment: sorry i saw the answer just now, thank you